# Choosing the correct form of verb

Tags: sequence-of-tenses

I was doing an exercise and there was a sentence --

> I ___________ Rahim at the zoo.

And I had to choose the correct verb form. Options were

**saw** , **have seen**, **had seen** 
I think all the three options are correct. They only change the meaning of the sentence. Am I right?

Comment: Of course, those verb forms are all correct and as far as English is concerned the sentence would work just fine with any one of them. Which one fits best depends purely on context. Without additional context, you can't say much. So, you're absolutely right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Giving the question a formal answer using Michael Rybkin's answer.

> Of course, those verb forms are all correct and as far as English is concerned the sentence would work just fine with any one of them. Which one fits best depends purely on context. Without additional context, you can't say much. So, you're absolutely right.